# Why is this cURL post request to login not working?

Tags: php, curl, xampp, php-curl

I am trying to login [here](https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/login/).

When I login manually and check the browser console -> network -> post -> headers/parameters, I get the following:-

```
form_key: viiRqZigH0YPC9wu
login[username]: myusername
login[password]: mypassword
send:
```

Please note that `form_key` changes everytime I login and `send` is always empty.
Hence, I have used the following code for my `cURL POST` request:-

```
$data = array(
    'login[username]' => 'myusername',
    'login[password]' => 'mypassword',
    'send' => '',
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/login/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // to allow redirections
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // to avoid error
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // to send info
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); // to save cookie data for login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // to get the html
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    var_dump($error_msg);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

But it just loads the login page and nothing happens, not even an error for invalid login.

Comment: Don't you need the `form_key`?

Comment: @apokryfos The form_key is different everytime one logs in, so how do I use it?

Comment: Get the form page first and scrape the key out of it and then send the request. It could be that the form key is a [CSRF token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Synchronizer_token_pattern). Make sure you use the same cookie jar so you simulate a user session

Comment: @apokryfos The whole html is coming as `string` in `$response`. My `regex` won't get the `form_key` value. Could you guide me here please?

Comment: What regex are you using? You can consider using the [PHP DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead

Comment: Do not switch `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` off.

Comment: @Dharman I have to do that or it gives an error.

Comment: @apokryfos Okay am trying with PHP DOM. Let me get back to you in a few minutes.

Comment: [See this article](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software). You can download the cert from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Comment: @Dharman I don't get error now, but the login still doesn't happen.

Comment: @apokryfos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559115/why-is-this-php-dom-parse-with-getattribute-not-working

Comment: @apokryfos I got the form_key but how do I post login info in the same cURL request? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561025/how-to-get-and-post-information-in-a-single-curl-request

Comment: It will be a different cURL request - the first is via GET and then the login is via POST - ensuring that you pass all captured cookies and the correct key, username and password - in addition to any other fields that might be in the form

Answer (score 2):

several reasons, can easily identify a couple of them:

1: you you need a cookie session before sending the login request, but your code does not create a cookie session first.

2: you need a CSRF token with your login request, but you don't fetch the CSRF token prior to logging in (the CSRF token is received together with the cookie session, you get both the CSRF token and the cookie session in the same response, by the way.)

3: you send the login parameters in the `multipart/form-data`-format, but this login page uses the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-format

4: this page needs a lot of custom HTTP headers in the login request, none of which your code is providing (including but not limited to `X-Magento-Action: customer_account_loginPost` and `X-XSS-Protection: 1`)

also just an observation, your login error checking code is sorely lacking.