# Why is this PHP DOM parse with getAttribute not working?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, html-parsing

[From this page](https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/login/), I want to get the `value` of the `input` tag with the name `form_key`. But I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method simple_html_dom::getAttribute() in test.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in test.php on line 9
```

Please note that I am using PHP Simple DOM parser.

PHP:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/login/');

if($html->getAttribute('name') =='form_key'){
    echo $html->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: you can put the simple_html_dom.php content?

Comment: The HTML itself doesn't really have attributes. I'm assuming you need to find the element first by e.g. doing `$html->find('input')` and then iterating through the results until you find the one where the name is `form_key` I'm not too familiar with simple_html_dom but that seems to be among the first examples in https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

Comment: Everything I found about it used `$html->find()` instead of 'getAttribute()'. I think you are one step too far. `getAttribute()` can be used on elements only.

Comment: Start with something like `$html->find('input[name=form_key]')`, go from there. https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm#section_find

Comment: @04FS I am now getting a never-ending array. Keeps loading forever.

Comment: What, with that one single line? Edit your question to show the current code, please.