# How to get and post information in a single cURL request?

Tags: php, json, parsing, curl, dom

Is it possible to get the `value` of an `input` and also `post` information in the same `cURL` request?

Reason:
I am trying to login [here](https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/login/) using cURL, however, the login form generates a unique key in the `value` of the `input` named `form_key`. So, I want to first get that value then post the username and password to successfully login.

PHP (not working, gives a blank page with nothing in source code):

```
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/login/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // to allow redirections
//curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // to avoid error
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, true); // to send info
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); // to save cookie data for login
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // to get the html
$response2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($response2);

$val = $html->find('input[name=form_key]');
$form_key = $val[0]->value;

$data = array(
    'form_key' => $form_key,
    'login[username]' => 'myusername',
    'login[password]' => 'mypassword',
    'send' => '',
);
```

P.S.
When I login manually and check the browser console -> network -> post -> headers/parameters, I get the following:-

```
form_key: viiRqZigH0YPC9wu
login[username]: myusername
login[password]: mypassword
send:
```

UPDATE.
TWO SEPARATE cURL REQUESTS (still now working):

include('simple_html_dom.php');

```
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/login/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // to allow redirections
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); // to save cookie data for login
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // to get the html
$response2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($response2);

$val = $html->find('input[name=form_key]');
$form_key = $val[0]->value;

$data = array(
    'form_key' => $form_key,
    'login[username]' => 'myusername',
    'login[password]' => 'mypassword',
    'send' => 'Anmelden'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/login/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // to allow redirections
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // to avoid error
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // to send info
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); // to read data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // to get the html
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    var_dump($error_msg);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Note from the [CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR.html) *Note that libcurl doesn't read any cookies from the cookie jar. If you want to read cookies from a file, use `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE.`*  You need *both*. Your first request will write the cookies to the cookie jar (and therefore needs `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`) the second one will need to read the cookies from the Jar using `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` to ensure the same session is used. This is necessary because the CSRF protection token is associated with the session cookie.

Comment: @apokryfos Okay but am I to use `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` in both or only the first request? Because in second request we are sending username and password.

Comment: First request you use `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` this will store the cookies the server sends. In the 2nd request you use both `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` which will send the cookies back to the server and then save any new/modified cookies that come from the server. The server will then cross-reference the form key with the session cookie it receives to ensure it's coming from the same person.

Comment: @apokryfos I tried that and its not working. Code updated in post.

Comment: The login url in the form in that page is `https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/loginPost/` . You seem to be calling the wrong one

Comment: @apokryfos IT WORKED! When I used `loginPost` instead of 'login' in the second request. Yes thank you so much. Make it an answer and I will mark it. Oh my god, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a bit of an intro of what's going on.

`form_key` seems to be used as a form of CSRF protection specifically it is a [synchronizer token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Synchronizer_token_pattern).

In short what happens is, a user visits a web page, the web page creates a session for the user and generates a unique token. The server then attaches that unique token to the form as a hidden field. When a user submits that form then it is submitted with that hidden field and the server can cross-reference that the token received is the same as the one that was sent.

However the critical part is that the server needs to be aware of who the user is, and that is done through the session. The session is maintained via a session cookie, which is why the session cookie is necessary.

To correctly simulate a real user you need to store the cookies the server sends you on first visit, this is done using the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` :

```php
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/login/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // to allow redirections
//curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // to avoid error
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POST, true); // to send info
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); // to save session cookie
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // to get the html
$response2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);
```

after you've done this and retrieved the CSRF token by scraping the page you need to submit this along with the corresponding cookies:

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/loginPost/"); //Make sure you have the correct URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // to allow redirections
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // to avoid error
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // to send info
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); // to read cookie data
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); // optional, this will update existing cookies and add new ones if needed.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // to get the html
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    var_dump($error_msg);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

This should allow the server to load the correct session for which the CSRF token was created in the first place and then verify that token you're sending.

As a sidenote: The reason for the token is simple. If I make a webpage which tricks users to post directly to another webpage this token is a piece of data that I can never have access to as it is only shared with the user directly so 3rd parties can't access it. It might make automations such as yours harder to implement but it is very effective for user security.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot but now I am facing a new problem of navigating to another page after successful login. Could this be also about cookie? Do you mind taking a look please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573969/how-do-i-navigate-to-different-pages-after-logging-in-via-curl

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is not possible.  Not because of cURL or PHP limitations, but simply because of causality.  Consider the logical set of steps being performed.  In order to send the login request, you must first know the `form_key`.  In order to know the `form_key` you must first request the login page.

To put it simply, you can't make use of information that you don't have yet.

- Make the first HTTP request to get the form information.  (Specifically the `form_key` value that you need.)
- Make the second HTTP request to send the login information, including the data you fetched from the first request.

There's no reason to try to do this in a single step.

Comment: But if I do it in two separate requests, then the `form_key` will change because 'form_key' changes everytime page is loaded.

Comment: @Grey-lover: Your assumption is incorrect.  The `form_key` changes if you re-request the login page, yes.  So... don't re-request the login page.  Your first request is a GET to fetch the login page, your second request is a POST to log in.  You're simply using cURL to replicate exactly what a web browser is doing.

Comment: Followed this method, but it didn't work with two separate requests. Post updated with new code.

Comment: @Grey-lover: Define "didn't work".  In what specific way does it fail?  It's time for you to do some debugging.  Does the first HTTP request return the login page data?  Do you successfully get the `form_key` value from that data?  Is the second HTTP request made?  What data does it contain?  What is the server's response?  You can use tools like Fiddler to monitor HTTP requests from outside your code, allowing you to observe the full request/response data.

Comment: @Grey-lover: Please also keep in mind that you are beginning to stray from the original question being asked.  You had asked specifically whether it's possible to make a single HTTP request which contains information received from that same request.  To which the answer is no.  Now you're asking for debugging help when making two HTTP requests.  That's a very different question.  Fundamentally changing the nature of the question invalidates existing answers and makes the overall post confusing and unhelpful to future readers.

Comment: Sorry about it, I will correct the question once its resolved so that future readers are not confused. So the first request is successful as in the `form_key` is successfully returned. But the second request to do the login is not working. And by not working I mean, the login page loads because I do `echo $response;` but it seems the login data is not going through.

Comment: @Grey-lover: *"the login page loads"* - If the second request returns the login page then it would appear that it's not successfully logging in.  When you reverse-engineer the login process using your browser's debugging tools, is any additional information being sent in the second request that isn't being sent in your cURL's second request?  The comment on the question above about cookies may be relevant.  Essentially you're trying to reverse-engineer something, so you're going to have to be meticulous about any and all differences between the original and your attempt.

Comment: Could you please turn your focus for a second towards the form submit button named 'send'. When I login manually, the browser console -> network -> post -> headers/parameters shows send's value to be empty. So, how is one to press the 'send' button using cURL if it's value is empty?

Comment: @Grey-lover: You don't "press a button" with cURL.  But you can send values.  In your `$data` array you're already sending a blank value for `send`.  Are you saying that value isn't present in the resulting request?  Where do you confirm this?  Or are you saying that in the original browser interaction the value is not empty?  If so, what is it?  Capture the original and replicated requests using a tool like Fiddler and compare them.  What differences do you observe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194833/discussion-between-grey-lover-and-david).