# How do I navigate to different pages after logging in via cURL?

Tags: php, json, curl, dom, cookies

Login page - https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/login/
After successful login page - https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/loginPost/
Page I want to go to - https://b2b.chiemsee.com/damen

I have made 3 separate requests:
1) To get the CSRF token.
2) To make the login.
3) To navigate to the url I want to go to.

Until I added the third request, the login was working fine and taking me to `loginPost/` page but now it takes me back to the `login/` page. Does it have something to do with the cookie in the third request?

PHP:-

```
// login request one to get form_key

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/login/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // to allow redirections
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); // to save cookie data for login
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // to get the html
$response2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($response2);

$val = $html->find('input[name=form_key]');
$form_key = $val[0]->value;


// login request two to send form_key, username and password

$data = array(
    'form_key' => $form_key,
    'login[username]' => 'user',
    'login[password]' => 'pass',
    'send' => 'Anmelden'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/loginPost/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // to allow redirections
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // to send info
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); // to read data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // to get the html
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    var_dump($error_msg);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


// request three to open first category

$ch3 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_URL, "https://b2b.chiemsee.com/damen");
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // to allow redirections
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); // to read data
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // to get the html
$response3 = curl_exec($ch3);
if (curl_error($ch3)) {
    $error_msg3 = curl_error($ch3);
    var_dump($error_msg3);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch3);
echo $response3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.
I wasn't saving the new data (username and password) sent in second request, in the cookie file, with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); // to save cookie data for login
```

Updated code:

```
// login request one to get form_key

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/login/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // to allow redirections
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); // to save cookie data for login
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // to get the html
$response2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($response2);

$val = $html->find('input[name=form_key]');
$form_key = $val[0]->value;

// login request two to send form_key, username and password

$data = array(
    'form_key' => $form_key,
    'login[username]' => 'user',
    'login[password]' => 'pass',
    'send' => 'Anmelden'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://b2b.chiemsee.com/customer/account/loginPost/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // to allow redirections
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // to avoid error
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // to send info
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); // to read data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); // to save cookie data for login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // to get the html
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    var_dump($error_msg);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);
//echo $response;

// request three to open first category

$ch3 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_URL, "https://b2b.chiemsee.com/damen");
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // to allow redirections
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); // to read data
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // to get the html
$response3 = curl_exec($ch3);
if (curl_error($ch3)) {
    $error_msg3 = curl_error($ch3);
    var_dump($error_msg3);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch3);
echo $response3;
```

Comment: stop using simple_html_dom, it's an old unmaintained library and made completely redundant in modern PHP thanks to the DOMDocument and DOMXPath classes, which are php-builtins.  use ```form_key=(new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($response2)))->query("//input[@name='form_key']")->item(0)->getAttribute("value");``` instead.

Comment: @hanshenrik Do I have to include any library or can I directly use DOMDocument and DOMXPath in my PHP 7.x code?

Comment: no library required, the only requirement this is that your PHP installation was *NOT* compiled with `--disable-xml` :) (xml is enabled by default, and it's highly unusual to compile PHP with --disable-xml , so it's not a real-world concern imo)

Answer (score 0):

> 2) To make the login.

that code never worked in the first place, you just have insufficient login-error-checking code to realize it.

replace

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    var_dump($error_msg);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

with

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    var_dump($error_msg);
    exit;
}
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($response);
$xp=new DOMXPath($domd);
$login_errors=array();
foreach($xp->query("//*[contains(@class,'error-msg')]") as $login_error){
    $login_error=trim($login_error->textContent);
    if(!empty($login_error)){
        $login_errors[]=$login_error;
    }
}
if(!empty($login_errors)){
    throw new \RuntimeException("login errors: ".print_r($login_errors,true));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

and you'll see that you get an error during login.